# Custom Outlook Mail App not working in Android and IPad

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have developed custom Outlook Mail App for Outlook Web App in Office 365. Its working fine in Outlook Web App from browser. But when I try to run the same app from OWA app in IPad and Android, I am facing an error.

The error says that

> Something went wrong! We couldn't start this add-ins

Please provide some reference from which I can make my app working from mobile app too.

Comment: Please tell us what kind of programming language / IDE you have used, how you tested it, how / where you got that error from. As it is, your question no details to where it might go wrong.

Comment: thanks for the response. Will update the question with more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the device iPad and Android is not related to the problem. Actually the web addins runtime can detect if the device is tablet or phone and may use different urls for loading.

Look at your `<FormSettings>` You must have something like that and make sure that all urls (if you use different ones) serve a correct addin.

For example make sure that the web page loads correctly and sets the `Office.Initialize` javascript callback function

```
<FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:44301/addinread"/>
        <RequestedHeight>280</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
      <TabletSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:44301/addinread/tablet" />
        <RequestedHeight>280</RequestedHeight>
      </TabletSettings>
      <PhoneSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:44301/addinread/phone" />
      </PhoneSettings>
    </Form>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:44301/addinwrite"/>
      </DesktopSettings>
      <TabletSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:44301/addinwrite/tablet" />
      </TabletSettings>
      <PhoneSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:44301/addinwrite/phone" />
      </PhoneSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I but I have to set the value as <RequestedHeight>216</RequestedHeight>

Answer (score 1):

Are the URLs you are using in the SourceLocation element accessible from Internet? If you device is connecting via your provider network, add-in resources hosted inside your intranet (or localhost) won't be accessible and you'd get this error.